# Always specify variable type

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using TypeScript, ESLint and @typescript-eslint. I want to always specify variable type and get an error when I don't:

```
const myVariable = 1; // -> error
const myVaribale: number = 1 // -> ok
```

I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Comment: You have linter configured so you always have to specifiy a variable type

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

add to .eslint.js

```
'@typescript-eslint/typedef': [
      'error',
      {
        arrayDestructuring: true,
        arrowCallSignature: true,
        arrowParameter: true,
        callSignature: true,
        memberVariableDeclaration: true,
        parameter: true,
        propertyDeclaration: true,
        objectDestructuring: true,
        variableDeclaration: true,
        variableDeclarationIgnoreFunction: true,
      },
    ],
'@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types': 0,
```